# how to launch Visual Studio with custom environment variables?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, environment-variables

Normally when you launch an application from cmd.exe the application inherits the environment variables set by the launching cmd.exe instance.

However, when Visual Studio is launched from the command line, the Visual Studio process inherits the values of the environment variables as set at the system-level. (This can be confirmed using Process Explorer.)

Why does Visual Studio behave this way and how can this behavior be overridden?

(Note that these questions do not concern environment variables relevant to project compilation or application debugging. They concern the Visual Studio process itself.)

Comment: Offhand I'd say it's respawning itself with a custom environment. [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762270) has the option `bInherit` that determines whether the new environment inherits from the current process.